# 'WordPress' Transliteration of Permalinks Available on one Website, but Not on the Second One

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I have two websites, with the same version of 'WordPress' (4.9.1), installed on both (hosted on the same provider). On the first one I set my language to be Serbian Cyrillic. On the second one I made it to be multilingual, by turning on Network Setup. One language is English and second one is Serbian Cyrillic again.  When I type in a post or a page title on the first website, WordPress automatically transliterates it from Cyrillic to Latin script (I found this option in the Settings / General section - on the bottom page, and turned it on). HOWEVER, the same option is missing on the second installation of the multilingual / Cyrillic website. Does anybody know why and how to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the file **sr_RS.php** in \wp-content\languages\ location. And this file was responsible for the field in options and for transliterating permalinks. Probably I've put it over there myself, but it seems now that I forgot that :).
Anyway I found solution and can proceed with building my website.

Answer (score 0):

There is one plugin for the WordPress what can solve your problems regarding complete transliterations and also permalinks.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/serbian-transliteration/